# Bios shown two identical HD Dell xps13-9333

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, dell-xps

[image: BiosDell A06 11/7/2014]
What cause bios-A06-11/7/2014 to show two HD with identical address'. If that normal Why? if not How to fix it?

Comment: Used Pcs comes in many forms. Don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the selection field is titled "File System List". Your disk has two file systems - that is, partitions, formatted in a way that your firmware can understand - and so either of those could possibly contain an UEFI bootloader file.

Having a setup menu that allows editing UEFI boot settings in this way is a good thing if you plan dual-booting or any other more complex system configurations.

If you ever lose your UEFI firmware settings ("BIOS settings"), you might need to know the Windows UEFI bootloader path name: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi

Comment: Now, does normal formatting method will return hd to original condition.

Comment: Normal usb linux installation seems to had fixed.